# How can I make this skeleton a little more realistic?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I've made this open type hourglass, which I am happy with in terms of graphical style and realism, but the key feature is the skeleton inside of it. I have failed to make the skeleton match (in any sense of the word) the rest of the hourglass.

Without Skeleton:
[image: Without skeleton]

With Skeleton:

[image: With skeleton]

As you can see, the skeleton looks quite bad. What could I do to improve the overall look?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of image is the skelton? vector grafic or bitmap? Size etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally try to sharpen up the skeleton and add more realism through usage of highlights and shadows. your hourglass has highlights and shadows and therefor so should your skeleton inside it.

also be careful when sharpening the skeleton. it is already very grainy and sharpening it will only accentuate it even further. try to smooth it out.

another point I wanted to mention is that in comparison to the base of your hourglass the top of the hourglass is in a wrong angle. the front should be more raised up. and also the circle at the top is a bit too wide judging by the side tips of the hourglass.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. Sadly, I do not have enough time (as this is for a project due soon) to fix the perspective of the hourglass, but I will definitely attempt to add highlights/shadows the the skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

Realistic? You might find a stock image of a 3D skeleton, as opposed to a blurry and somewhat pixelated line drawing. You don't use lines in your hourglass, so in keeping with the style something without lines in the skeleton is ideal.

Also, what makes the skeleton stand as such? Gravity should pull him to flop against the glass, bend his knees, twist his body a bit. At least, repositioning the arms to a more relaxed state might help, as right now he almost looks to have the attention of a cowboy ready to draw.

(Kudos on the shadows and texture on the wooden base!)